# Reading from an embedded resource stream

Tags: c++-cli, stream, resources

I've been trying to access an image resource named "IndexPointer.jpg" in an embedded RESX file called "Images.resx". GetManifestResourceNames() returns a single value - SCtor.Images.resources".

Assembly::GetExecutingAssembly()->GetManifestResourceStream("SCtor.Images.resources.IndexPointer.jpg")

only returns a nullptr. Obviously, I've got the manifest name wrong. What would be the correct one ?

Comment: If you wonder why there are no answers, this is because anyone doesn't do such things in C++/CLI. Reproduce the problem in C# and ask in any C# forum. Than translate to C++/CLI.

Comment: Well, from what I can tell, the only difference b'ween the c# and the C++/CLI version of this code is the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally figured it out. Strangely, I recall coming across (and trying out) the working solution and disregarding it. In any case, I instantiated a ResourceManager object with my assembly's resource and used its GetObject method to extract the embedded image.

```
ResourceManager^ resources = gcnew ResourceManager("<rootNamespace>.<resourceName>", Assembly::GetExecutingAssembly());
Bitmap^ Image1 = gcnew Bitmap(dynamic_cast<Image^>(resources->GetObject("<nameOfTheImageResourceWithoutItsExtension>")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the assembly with Reflector to find out the correct resource name.

Comment: No good - It only shows what I already know, the ResourceName and names of the image resources in it.